# Use different jre for projects and for eclipse launch

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, ide

May be its a newbie question...

I want to use latest eclipse available. It requires Java 8. However, our company uses java 6 for all projects.

So:

1. Should I download eclipse that is compatible with Java 6 only ?
2. or I can configure Java 6 for all the projects regardless what eclipse uses?
3. Would there be any issues, if its possible to use two versions (one for eclipse and another one for project)?

I know its a newbie questions. But the search did not yield a proper response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you can use the latest Java for Eclipse. The JDK used for project can be configured per project or per workspace. You can install as much JDKs as you desire. i.e. You can start Eclipse using a 32Bit JDK while using a 64Bit JDK for Java EE-Servers or Projects, it has basically nothing to do with the JRE used for Eclipse. You just need to set it up.

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies things up.